# How to get the number of Processors on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, xna, windows-phone-7.1

I'm wondering how to get the number of processors on Windows Phone... as documented in the MSDN the following statement always throws a MethodAccessException:

```
Environment.ProcessorCount
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
j3d

Comment: I suppose Windows Phones are all single core. WP8 introduces support for multi-core phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/76703/466036.aspx) forum post, which links to the MSDN [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that you mentioned, you can't get the processor count programatically on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 2):

As described in MSDN this Property has a `SecurityCriticalAttribute` that makes for internal only, you can't use from your application. From MSDN:

> This member has a SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute on Silverlight
>   for Windows Phone, because the attribute was present in Silverlight 3.
>   This attribute restricts this member to internal use. Application code
>   that uses this member throws a MethodAccessException.